# How to remove relations while iteration with UNWIND using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

The following query getting all groups of specific user then 
unwind on each result(each group) and should remove all incoming relations only if count relations to that group is 1.

```
example: group1<-user1  (will delete the incoming relationship to the group)

         group1-<user1 
         group1-<user2 (will remain all incoming relationships to the group)
```

can assist complete it?

```
MATCH (me:userId{{1})-[rel:relation_group]-(allGroups:GROUP)
unwind userGroups as group  
 //how to use CASE or WHERE in order to check if this group 
has only 1 relationship just remove it
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `size` in `WHERE`, example :

```
MATCH (me:userId{{1})-[rel:relation_group]-(allGroups:GROUP)
WHERE size((allGroups)<-[:relation_group]-()) = 1
DELETE rel
```

You don't need to iterate, by default the subsequent clauses after a MATCH will be executed for each row found in the MATCH, so let's say the first `MATCH` returns the following :

```
me     rel     allGroups
1      rel3     node5
1      rel4     node6
```

Then the `DELETE` will be executed for the first row, then for the second row, etc...

Comment: but how do u iterate this way on each group? as u'll get list of groups and need to check for each one if the number of incoming relationships is 1 remove it else remain it

Comment: You don't need to iterate, just add the direction to the pattern in the WHERE clause

Comment: How the size actually iterate on each group from allGroups?

Comment: I added a little explanation

Comment: Thanks. so why  we have  UNWIND or FOREACH if we can iterate on results row by row as default behavior  ?

Comment: I suggest you take some available cypher online courses / tutorials / graphgists to learn more about cypher ;-)

Comment: you right. doing my best to cover it all. just every-time I find out new concepts

Comment: Thats cool to discover new stuff, otherwise we would be bored :)